# UIImagePickerController's cameraOverlayView is not displaying in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8

I am presenting `UIImagePickerController` like as follows,

```
if (!self.imagePickerController) self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

            CameraOverlay *overlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UI appFrameHeight])];
            overlay.delegate = self;
            self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

            int value = SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") ? 68 : 48;

            CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, value);
            self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = translate;

            CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1.333333, 1.333333);
            self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = scale;

 [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

its not displaying the overlay view. Pls anyone help me that how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At finally fixed this issue with the help of @Nookaraju answer from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947888/uialertview-and-uiactionsheet-not-displaying-properly-in-ios-8), this is fixed by removing the `setTitle:` method viewcontroller category form the app.

```
@implementation UIViewController (CustomeAction)
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title{
// YOU CODE///
}
@end
```

Removed the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it has helped setting the `frame` of the `Overlay` like this, use

```
CameraOverlay *overlay = [CameraOverlay new];
[overlay setFrame:self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame]; // important change
```

instead of

```
CameraOverlay *overlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UI appFrameHeight])];
```

Please feedback me...